# How to place rectangle in grid order?

Tags: java, grid, drawing

So far, my program draws many rectangles and the locations of the rectangles are random (not nice). How can I place the rectangle in grid order so that it look appealing?

Comment: Are you rendering rectangles (with Graphics, Graphics2D) or arranging components (JComponent) on a panel?

Comment: I have the same problem arranging my polygon drawing in grid order. I think the grid manager is suitable only for JComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid manager like [GridLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)